# Can I just use a Generic Repository and a Generic Service class for the whole project?

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

There is this generic repository implementation

http://www.itworld.com/development/409087/generic-repository-net-entity-framework-6-async-operations

By the looks of it , it seems that i can just have a single generic repository for my whole project and for almost all of the entities in the database it will work fine. For the ones that it doesn't , i can create a more specific repository , e.g. `MembershipRepository` which derives from the base repository and overrides the methods as needed, such as Find for example.

Now one could also write a generic service class too.... similar to the above, and then creating only a few more specific services.

That will drastically reduce the project size. No need to write redundant repositories per entity, and a much smaller number of service layer classes.

Surely it can't be that simple. Is there a catch to this? Let's ignore for a moment that EntityFramework has the repository+UOW pattern built in and repository pattern isn't needed.

Comment: What you want to know exactly?

Comment: That if there is a major drawback to this simplistic approach?

Comment: Yeah it is. The generic repository is an anti pattern breaking SoC and coupling your business layer to persistence. EF or any ORM never has and never will have a repository included as it defeats the purpose of the Repository pattern. Does it work? Of course it does, it's great for EF tutorials and CRUD apps. I mean why use proper OOP  when procedural code works well too? Yeah, it's all about maintainability, but you'll find that only when it's too late/expensive to change this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do.

I am torn about it honestly. For smaller domains its perfectly fine and works a treat. For larger ones (like the one I am working with currently), your repository can never really be *generic enough* to warrant a single one.

For example, the generic repository in the code base that I currently work with is now littered with all sorts of very specific methods for things like eager fetching, paging, etc. Its much more than what it started out as. Looking back at the revision history, it once only had `GetAll`, `GetById`, `Create` and `Update` methods. Now it has things like `GetAllEagerFetch` with overloads for various `JOIN` types, `GetAllPaged`, `GetAllPagedEagerFetch`, `DeleteById`, `ExecuteStoredProcedure`, `ExecuteSql` (yuck), etc. There is a lot more.

One way around this is to perhaps follow the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) so that your repository can be huge and generic but consumers only care about what they need to care about. I don't particularly like that though.

That being said - we have moved away from a Repository-style setup in more recent projects. We prefer a [CQRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) setup now with `Command` and `Query` objects that have a specific purpose. This leans more towards the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) instead (doesn't follow it to the "Uncle Bob degree".. but the classes have some well defined responsibilities).

Comment: You weren't using a repository in the first place, just a DAO named repository. CQRS is unrelated to repositories. My God how much harm that stupid MS tutorial did for the Repository pattern.

Comment: I am aware CQRS and repositories are unrelated - I never said they were. I also don't consider "Generic Repository" to be synonymous with the "Repository pattern".. in the same way that CQS and CQRS are different.